# Apache Jena Split Graph based on Parent

Tags: jena, ontology, apache-jena

I am learning Apache Jena. I am able to get Statements, Objects, Subject and graph.

i want to split the graph based on parent example: B and C are child of A and further more D is Child of B. Again in Same graph A1 if parent of B1,C1 and D1. So I want to get details of Graph into 2 different Sections.

```
A -> [B -> [D],C] and A1 -> [B1,C1,D1]
```

I am using Apache Jena API
Let me know if these is any other api available to process and am reading Data from Turtle File.

Thanks

Comment: Consider using SPARQL.

Comment: how can i query using sparkql for child and subchild of child

Comment: Start with a SPARQL tutorial.

Questions about SPARQL are best if they include some (small) real data and a query you have tried.

Comment: I can't use Sparkql